# Is UPDATE containing .WRITE clause atomic when multiple columns are updated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is the following statement an atomic operation?

```
UPDATE [table1]
SET column1=@val1, column2.WRITE(@val2, NULL, 0) WHERE table1_id=@id
```

or should it be placed inside a transaction to ensure that none or both columns are updated in case of error situations?

Columns are defined as:

```
column1 int not null, 
column2 varbinary(max) not null
```

Comment: Yes, it's atomic. It doesn't matter whether it's 1 row or 1 million, 1 column or 20.  INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE are all atomic operations.

Comment: A single update statement is itself atomic, no need to put it in a transaction.

Comment: @Furqan: if you want to be able to roll it back, then putting it into an explicit transaction does make sense.

Comment: Someone should answer this question, and say where the docs say that an UPDATE is atomic. I would upvote.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I explicitly mentioned that `a single statement` , if you need to execute a single update and roll it back, then what would be the use of it except for testing?

Comment: @Furqan: exactly that: testing and verifying that everything was changed correctly. What if you missed a condition in the `WHERE` clause? It might not be that important for an UPDATE statement, but for a DELETE statement this very important I think.

Comment: Thanks, so using .WRITE clause does not change the atomic nature of an UPDATE statement then.

Answer (score 2):

It is one statement.  In SQL Server, each statement carries an implied transaction.  Here is another answer if you'd like more details.

[What does a transaction around a single statement do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171749/what-does-a-transaction-around-a-single-statement-do)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an MSDN reference on [Autocommit Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which states that:

> Autocommit mode is the default transaction management mode of the SQL Server Database
>   Engine. Every Transact-SQL statement is committed or rolled back when it
>   completes. If a statement completes successfully, it is committed; if
>   it encounters any error, it is rolled back.

[Modifying Large-Value (max) Data in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx) using UPDATE .WRITE is not documented to affect the UPDATE statement transaction.