# Is Mysql/Mariadb delete Query transactional? and its performance for huge no. of rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, sql-delete, transactional

Q1: Does a delete query run as a whole transaction in mysql/mariadb. So if we have 1 million rows to delete, will mysql/mqriadb server delete it as a whole or if after deleting some rows something goes wrong deleted rows will get restored.

Q2: Should we need to delete rows in a single delete query (irrespective of   how many rows need to deleted) or should we need to place a limit in delete query and perform delete in batches. If batching is required  at what number (no. of rows to deleted) should we think of it.

Comment: Your first question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856370/transaction-necessary-for-single-update-query

Comment: For your second question, it really depends on how many records you plan on deleting.  Do you really think you will have a frequent need to delete millions of records?

Comment: we need to purge approx 1 lakh to 1 million of records every day.

Comment: About your second question. The MySQL Documentation states: If you are deleting many rows from a large table, you may exceed the lock table size for an InnoDB table. They suggest to use a temporary table in this case. There is a similar Question on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448868/delete-huge-amounts-of-data-from-huge-table and a [blog article](http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/12/deleting-huge-number-of-records-in-mysql.html) by Rashid Kumar : Deleting huge number of records in MySQL

Answer (score 5):

In InnoDB, a `DELETE` of *any size* is transactional.  Deleting a million will be slow, mostly because of the need to prepare for a possible `ROLLBACK`.

I cover the rest of the questions in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig , including advice on what to do.

Comment: Based on your article's chunk strategy i developed a procedure and deleting 1000 rows inside a loop, i observed `The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size`. My `innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M` and `autocommit=1`. How is this possible? Is there any way that locks are released after each query? Or is it anything related to the loop inside which the delete is being run?

Comment: @ismathullah - Ouch.  How much RAM do you have?  How old is your MySQL?  128M is an old default.  Decrease the 1000 to, say, 100 until you work out the optimal buffer_pool_size.

Comment: I am using MariaDB-10.0.35, MySQL 5.6. on an 8C 16GB server. Decreasing may work, but i m delaing with deletion of 50+ million records. Once one dele query is done within an iteration, that lock is to be released right. How does that work? Is there anything special about deletions within a loop?

Comment: @ismathullah - Depends on the setting of `autocommit` and whether you used `BEGIN`.

Comment: `autocommit=1` and i have used `BEGIN` to start the procedure definition, i believe that wont put everything into a transaction. Will test with seperate transaction block for each iterations. Will publish result if it helps.

Comment: @ismathullah - `BEGIN` cancels autocommit=1.  The transaction will end with an explicit `COMMIT`.