# Consistent counter column increment?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, hibernate, concurrency, sql-update

This is the `update` statement that I have, which seems to be doing what i want it to do, i.e. increment the counter column on specific records of the given table:

```
update config_per_geo 
inner join country on config_per_geo.country_id = country.id 
set counter = counter + 1 
where product_id in (?, ?, ?) 
and (country.iso_code = ? or 
    (country.iso_code = 'ZZZ' and product_id not in 
        (select product_id 
         from (select * from config_per_geo) as cpg1 
         inner join country as cty1 on cpg1.country_id = cty1.id 
         where cty1.iso_code = ?)
    )
)
```

(`cpg1` aliasing seems to be necessary because of [this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause))

The thing is that this query should be performed from the web application (per HTTP request), where multiple simultaneous requests are possible, in other words in a concurrent, multi-threaded  environment. Further more, I'd need to reset the counter field once a day, and I thought I'd perform this through a CRON job, or something, by running:

```
start transaction;  
select counter from config_per_geo for update;  
update config_per_geo set counter = 0;  
commit;
```

**The questions:** what I wonder about is whether these two queries (transactions) will always leave `counter` column in the consistent state, and more specifically - will the first query consistently and atomically increment the counter when executed concurrently (from simultaneous request threads) ?

I suppose they should, but I couldn't for the life of me be 100% sure based on MySQL documentation...

Answer (score 1):

You dont need the transaction code in the second statement. Just use

```
update config_per_geo set counter = 0;
```

config_per_geo will be kept consistent.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171807/4350148 regarding single statement transactions

Comment: yeah, I figured this out right after posing the question - `select.. for update` is superfluous here, as plain `update` will lock the rows. However the first statement is still a bit fuzzy for me.. I'll also need to increment a few more counters in this table.