# Should i use transaction for single Select, Insert, Update, Delete statements in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ado.net

Should i use transaction for single Select, Insert, Update, Delete statements in SQL Server?

Comment: Depends on transaction settings...

Comment: Depends on your use case.

Comment: do you only want yes or no for an answer?

Comment: Settings are default. I want an explanation

Comment: I assume, lets say we have mutiple users calling the same SP, that has a single Select statement. Considering concurreny..when the first users calls the SP, will the call from second user be on hold.

I mean, if i use Transaction for a single select statements. Are there any kind of lock acquired on the calls?

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/43254/6137

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a transaction around a single statement do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171749/what-does-a-transaction-around-a-single-statement-do)

Answer (score 1):

Could be useful in case you need to avoid phantoms, dirty reads or other issues like those.
It could also depends on the framework you're using to perform such operations, but in a very simple scenario (one single workflow) transactions are not needed

Comment: Ok. Let me take anothor scenario.

Comment: I have a stored procedure written. It has three select statements. 
Getting data from three seperate tables.

First table is primary to the second table. And

Second table is primary to the third table.

Should i keep these three select statements in a transaction within a SP.

If yes, why?

If no, why?

Comment: if you're sure no one is performing any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on those tables in the meantime the answer is no, you don't need any transaction, since reading a table doesn't alter its records and you'll always have repeatable reads. In case someone should change the records, then you need transactions to avoid phantoms, dirty reads and company issues

Comment: Ok. What if the INSERT/Update/Delete statements are in transaction.

Will the select queries wait to get the data, after the DML statements have committed.

Comment: Yes and no: it depends on the isolation level and/or the lock type on the table. The lower isolation level usually let you have concurrent ops, while the highest used with a table lock guarantee no clash is occurring making the distinct ops serialized.