# Return error message from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

The question should be quite simple, but I can't figure out the answer nor why my stored procedure is not working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest_Delete
@ID int
AS
    begin tran
        declare @err int
        declare @errMesage nvarchar(max)
        set @errMesage = ''
        set @err = 0

        delete from Test
        where ID = @ID

        set @err = @@ERROR
        set @errMesage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        if @err = 0 
           commit tran
        else 
        begin
            RAISERROR(N'Could not delete !Error nr: %d. Message: %s', 1, 16, @err, @errMesage)
            rollback tran
        end
```

This procedure runs ok, but in case of FK constraint on the `delete` statement it runs into an error (which is good) and I would like to catch the error.

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Procedure spTest_Delete, Line 12
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_TEstFK_Test". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table
>   "dbo.Test", column 'ID'. The statement has been terminated.
>
> Could not delete!
>   Error nr: 547. Message: (null) Msg 50000, Level 1, State 16

I always get null for my message variable, even though the `delete` statement throws an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use TRY CATCH and catch your error like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
   delete from Test
    where  ID = @ID
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    SET @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    BREAK
END CATCH
```

Comment: Try catch did the trick, but I'm still a little confused, why it doesn't work without try catch.

Comment: @CiucaS:- Usually it is recommended to use TRY..CATCH to catch the error. You can try to use `if ISNULL(@err,0) = 0`

Comment: how does ErrorMessage is catched in .net side ?

Comment: I see that `RaiseError` will return (via .NET Exception) its `msg_str` Parameter to the Caller if the Caller is a .NET app, but how does it return it, if the Caller is another Stored Procedure?  The `Error_Message` (and all `Error_*` Functions) return `Null`, immediately after `Exec` on a Stored Procedure that called `RaiseError` right before it `return`-ed and it also doesn't trigger the `Catch` Block in the Calling Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Tom I would love to know the answers to your comment

Answer (score 14):

You might want to start using [TRY..CATCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) block in your procedures

> Implements error handling for Transact-SQL that is similar to the
>   exception handling in the Microsoft Visual C# and Microsoft Visual C++
>   languages. A group of Transact-SQL statements can be enclosed in a TRY
>   block. If an error occurs in the TRY block, control is passed to
>   another group of statements that is enclosed in a CATCH block.

So your procedure could be rewritten as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest_Delete @ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DELETE
            FROM Test
            WHERE ID = @ID;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END
```

Also, please note that you're running as single delete statement. It means that it doesn't need to be wrapped up in a transaction. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171749/what-does-a-transaction-around-a-single-statement-do) question explains why.

Your code becomes this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest_Delete @ID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        DELETE
        FROM Test
        WHERE ID = @ID;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END
```

Now why your `@errMessage` is always NULL? Because `ERROR_MESSAGE()` is valid ONLY IN CATCH BLOCK. That's written in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Returns the message text of the error that caused the CATCH block of a
>   TRY…CATCH construct to be run.

[Using TRY..CATCH in Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296.aspx) tells this:

> Error information is retrieved by using these functions from anywhere
>   in the scope of the CATCH block of a TRY…CATCH construct. **The error
>   functions will return NULL if called outside the scope of a CATCH
>   block**.